# NodeJS - Pass a variable between files but the variable needs to update

Tags: node.js

I have 2 files and I'm trying to pass a variable from one to another. tcp.js receives the variable, but if the variable changes in data.js, tcp.js doesn't see the change. Is there a way to do it so tcp.js does see the changes?

*data.js*

```
var {eventEmitter} = require('./events.js'); 
var storedData = 'Hello from Data';

var myEventHandler = function (data) {
    console.log(data)
    storedData = data;
}
eventEmitter.on('message-test', myEventHandler);

module.exports = { storedData };
```

*tcp.js*

```
var net = require('net');  
const config = require ('../config'); // various info
const port2 = config.TCP_PORT || 8000;
const {storedData} = require ('./data.js');

// testing to see if the variable is changing
var interval = setInterval(function() {    
    console.log(storedData);
},2000)

var server = net.createServer();
server.on('connection', function(socket) {
    var remoteAddress = socket.remotePort;   
    console.log('A new client has connected!');   

    socket.write(storedData);

    socket.once('close', function() {
        console.log('The connection from %s has been closed', remoteAddress);
        clearInterval(interval);
    });       
});

server.listen(port2, function() {
    console.log('TCP server listening on %s', port2 );   
});
```

Comment: And what/where is `storeData` updated? What is happening? Error message?

Comment: inside myEventHandler in data.js

Comment: Thats not a answer on my question. What triggers the update/how does this code looks like? Provide a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: No error, tcp.js just keeps seeing the original value of storedData. It all works if I put the event handler and the tcp server inside of index.js but that seems like a messy way to do it. I want to have separate files as this will keep growing.

Comment: A minimal reproducable example will take some time. I will try to do that.

Comment: You can't do this with a static variable which will be copied by value.  You could do this with an object (which will be passed by reference, so that both pieces of code use the same object) or by exposing `storedData` via a function in data.js (so in tcp.js you'd access it via `storedData()` )

Comment: @Joe - Thanks! That's just what I needed. It's working now. How about making your comment into an answer so I can mark it as the solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't do this with a regular variable - those will be passed by value and thus copied.

You could return the value of a regular variable like this via a function -- so instead of exporting the variable, you export a function that returns the value of the variable.  You then call that function from the other module.

Alternately you could use an object ({}) since that is passed by reference, so if you export the object from one module and use it in another, they both refer to the same thing and can share state.